# Sim800l AT+COPS returns 0 and AT+CREG returns 0,3

Tags: connection, gsm, at-command, sim900

Yeah I know there is similar questions in this community But they didn't help.
It's for some days that I play with SIM800l.It's response to my at commands is good but when I want to send SMS I'll get problem.I think this Screenshot says most of story:

[AT commands and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy9py.png)
https://ibb.co/bXxwFQ

u can see that I have signal (AT+CSQ = 19).but my module can't find and connect to operator (forgot to test AT+CREG but it returns 0,3)
and I can set CREG to 1,3 by AT+CREG=1 command.Does it help?

oh at last I should say that I'm using lm2596 for supplying and my module blinks 70 times in a minute.more than 1 time in a sec (searching for network) and less than 2 time in a sec (connected)

ANY help would be appreciated

Comment: Screenshots like that are useless, you need to include the information as **text** directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not powering it up with enough supply. Your module does not automatically register to network. It happened to me when I power my sim800l with the arduino 5v, it works smoothly at first but it keeps on resetting after a while. Try to use at commands such as cband, cops, creg, and csca to manually register to network.